# 400 Bad Request when implementing custom friend selector

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to implement a custom multiple friend selector to invite users to my game. I get the list of users calling the Graph API call InvitableFriends, and create a UI for it.

After the user selects the corresponding users, I get all the invitation tokens of the users, and make a call to an App Request as follows:

```
public void InviteFriends(string message, string title, FacebookDelegate callback, string[] to = null, string data = "")
    {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) 
        {
            FB.AppRequest (message,
                  to,
                  "",
                  null,
                  null,
                  data,
                  title,
                  callback);
        } 
}
```

But when the call is made, I'm getting the following error:

```
400 Bad Request
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
FbDebug:Error(String)
Facebook.FallbackData:JSFallback(String)
Facebook.AsyncRequestDialogPost:CallbackWithErrorHandling(FBResult)
Facebook.<Start>c__Iterator0:MoveNext()
```

My callback function is never called, so I can't see what the error is.

I'm using Unity 4.3 & Facebook SDK 5.1

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I'm pretty confident that the issue is that in the TO parameter I'm passing the invite tokens that the Invitable Graph call is giving me, AND NOT THE Ids.

I tested the InteractiveConsole.cs example of friendsmash with the invitable token and it also failed. How can I get the ids of the invitable friends?

Comment: Are there an error message with the 400 Bad Request?

Comment: Just that error. If I take out the 'TO' parameter, the facebook implemented selector gets shown and works as expected.

Comment: I would suggest getting the HTTP request you do much easier to figure out what is wrong if you know what you send to Facebook

Comment: The problem is with the Token Ids gotten from the Invitable Friend Graph call. I Updated my Original Post.

Comment: You can not get the ids of invitable friends. And I agree that it is probably invite tokens that are the problem. But if you get the HTTP request you can verify that that is the case. You can also file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

just check the url request. It may be some thing wrong with it.
or
go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{app-id}/app-details/
in "app Info" section, choose the proper category and sub category.

Answer (score 0):

I  had a similar issue.. Figured out that FB.init() has to be called before using the invitable api. Without it you would get a "400 Bad Request"

I was keeping the old access token in playerprefs and just checking it again for validity and not actually initialising FB to save load time. But eventually I had to do FB.init()